# How to read cookie files in c# thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have this function for reading cookie files in C#:

```
private void getdocument()
{
 while (true)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
 }
}
```

I am invoking it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getdocument));
 MyThread.Start();
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
>
> Specified cast is not valid.

How to fix this?

Comment: This question is not related to `C` programming language. `C` and `C#` are totally different.

Comment: This will launch an infinitive amount of messageboxes. Is that what you want? You are also accessing the browser control from a different thread than the UI thread.

Comment: no i used msgboxes for testing purpose. i want read cookie data when it created .that's why i used threading.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see in Object Hierarchy structure `WebBrowser` is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, so you need to you it from the thread it was created on.

Fix :

```
private void getdocument()
{
    while (true)
    {

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: it generate following error: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code--Object reference not set to an instance of an object. but it work well inside the "if" condition after "while".

Comment: @user2351414 - the null reference is because you have not opened any website yet! before trying to get cookie, open a url :)